# ConcurrentSkipSet CompareTo Instant infinite loop

Tags: java, compare, comparator, java.time.instant

I am creating a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet` with a comparator. My comparator compares an Instant field in the object to determine the order. This is the comparator:

```
public int compare(myObj first, myObj second) {
        if (first == null || first.getTime() == null) {
            return 1; 
        }
        if (second == null || second.getTime() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        if ( first.getTime().isBefore(second.getTime()) {
            return -1;
        }
        else { 
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

When I use the above compartor 5/10 times it is stuck in an infinite loop. First is always after second , so the program always reach the else and return 1, however in some runs it just loops, it reaches the else but is just stuck constantly running the comparator... I can see this when I run in debug mode and also when adding extra logging. To clarify the 2 objects are not the same when it is stuck, so the issue isn't trying to add duplicated.
When I switch isBefore to isAfter like so, I don't get that behaviour, it runs as expected each time. My question is why would this happen?

```
    public int compare(myObj first, myObj second) {
        if (first == null || first.getTime() == null) {
            return 1; 
        }
        if (second == null || second.getTime() == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        if ( first.getTime().isAfter(second.getTime()) {
            return 1;
        }
        else { 
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Adding to the list implementation (boiled down for simplicity)

My concurrent skip set logic is very simple, I create the set with the compartor above, then myObj instant is initiated to now() + a predetermines number of minutes (hard coded so this calculation will not fail) then my obj is added to the concurrentskipset

```
private ConcurrentSkipListSet<MyObj> skipSetImpl= new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>(new MyObj.MyobjComp()); 

// added in a method, using Java Instant
foo.setTime( now.plus(60, ChronoUnit.SECONDS) ); 

this.skipSetImpl.add(foo); // add to concurrentSkipSet
```

Comment: two instants can never be equal with your logic

Comment: Yes they can't be equal with my logic and the way the program works they should never be equal. Each instant is set to the current time, and no 2 instances are created the the same time.

Comment: So you're using the set *purely* as a sorted list of distinct objects? You don't ever use the fact that sets eliminate duplicates, and you never check if the set already contains an object?

Answer (score 2):

You are not fulfilling the contract of `Comparator.compare()`. Whether this is the source of the problem you are asking about, without your `ConcurrentSkipSet` code we can’t tell, but it could very well be.

If two `MyObj` either are both `null`, one is `null` and the other has a `null` instant or both have a `null` instant, then your comparator cannot decide their order. If your skip set calls `compare(a, b)`, `a` should come last, but if next it calls `compare(b, a)`, suddenly `b` should come last. Could this cause it to loop? In any case it’s no nice property of a comparator to be inconsistent, and it will surely lead to problems with other classes that use a `Comparator`.

The documentation of the `compare` method says:

> The implementor must ensure that `sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))` for all `x` and `y`. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x)
> throws an exception.)

This is the part you are breaking. Your skip set should be able to rely on you keeping the contract.

You said:

> they can't be equal with my logic and the way the program works they
> should never be equal

If so, you need to decide one order for any two `MyObj`. One solution is to disallow nulls (throw an exception if a `null` occurs). Another is to decide that nulls *are* equal.

A terse way of defining a comparator that puts nulls last is through `Comparator.nullsLast()` and `Comparator.comparing()` (since Java 8):

```
    Comparator<MyObj> comp = Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(
            MyObj::getTime, Comparator.nullsLast(Instant::compareTo)));
```

`Comparator.nullsLast()` gives you a comparator that sorts nulls last and compares non-null objects using the comparator supplied as argument. I am also using the two-arg `comparing​(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor, Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)`. The first argument, `MyObj::getTime`, tells it to compare the instants, and the second argument is the comparator used to compare the instants — in this case again putting nulls last. The resulting comparator *does* fulfil the contract of `Comparator.comparing()`. Corner case: it will put `null` `MyObj` references before `MyObj` objects having a `null` instant, which is different from what your comparator did.

When I recommend the Java 8+ way of defining comparators, it’s not so much because it’s brief. It’s more because it is much harder to get wrong, including that it is hard to break the contract of the `compare` method.

**Link:** [Documentation of `Comparator.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T))

Comment: Thanks! I will change the first 2 if statements to meet the comparator contract. Whe it breaks however both have an instant so it doesn't enter the first 2 ifs, it loops on the last if and else.

Comment: That’s fishy. Is that `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet`? Could you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited the question to add my ConcurrentSkipSet code. Yes it's java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet. Is that enough for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Are you adding concurrently from more than one thread to have this behaviour? Are you initializing `now` for every object added?

Comment: No, I ran the code you have given me 10 times, and no infinite loop happened, so it doesn’t seem reproducible.